# Выбор значения submit кнопки для отправки .post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть код формы:

```
<form id="commentadd" action="/comment/add" method="POST">
<table border="1">

<input style="display: none;" type="text" name="num_clear" value="{$num_clear}" size="40">

<textarea type="text" name="text" id="userComment"></textarea>
<p class="text-center">
<button  id="like1" type="submit" name="like" value="1" >Good</button>
<button id="like0"  type="submit"  name="like" value="0" >Unknown</button>
<button id="like-1"type="submit" name="like" value="-1" >Bad</button>
</p>
</table>
</form>
```

Пытаюсь прикрутить передачу данных. Значение like берется в зависимости от нажатой submit кнопки (-1, 0 или 1). Как мне определять, какую кнопку нажали из этих 3, чтобы передавать нужное значение в перемененную term?

```
<script>
    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#commentadd").submit(function(event) {

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        /* get some values from elements on the page: */
        var $form = $(this),
                term = $form.find('button[id="like-1"]').val(),
                term = $form.find('button[id="like0"]').val(),
                term = $form.find('button[id="like1"]').val(),
                text = $form.find('textarea[id="userComment"]').val(),
                url = $form.attr('action');


        /* Send the data using post */
        var posting = $.post(url, {
            like: term,
            text: text
        });


    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>

var clickedButtonValue;

$('button[type="submit"]').click(function() {
  clickedButtonValue = $(this).val();
});

/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#commentadd").submit(function(event) {

  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $(this),
      text = $form.find('textarea[id="userComment"]').val(),
      url = $form.attr('action'),
      term = clickedButtonValue;

  /* Send the data using post */
  var posting = $.post(url, {
    like: term,
    text: text
  });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает отлично :)